# Wrong data in recyclerView after some time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have got a recycler view while for each item , i need to update the data every 20 seconds. For the adapter , I have used ListAdapter with DiffUtil.

```
private class TpaDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DataForWatch>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DataForWatch, newItem: DataForWatch): Boolean =
        oldItem.id == newItem.id

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DataForWatch, newItem: DataForWatch): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
}
```

Timer :

```
    inner class MyTimer(millisInFuture: Long, countDownInterval: Long, var progressBar: ProgressBar, var data: DataForWatch, var codeView: TextView) : CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        startTimer(progressBar, data, codeView) // Restart the timer
        getCode(data, codeView) // Assign the value to codeView ( the problematic textView i wrote about , above :P )
    }
}
```

To do so... i run a timer , where i pass the KEY ( based on which i will generate the data ) and the VIEW ( whose content is updated with new data every 20 seconds).

The problem is... everything is works fine as long as i keep scrolling . but... If i scroll down and stop at position ( lets say 5 ), the 5th item will be showing the data which is supposedly for the 2nd Item.

I believe it is because the view got recycled and hence the wrong view is being updated here. But , here are my doubts :

1. It displays the correct data when i see it for the first time , the problem arises only after the first update. If it was showing the right data for the first time , then it means that the right view is being updated by the Timer. How does it change after the first update ?
2. What's the right way to achieve this , if not by running a timer with the view as its param ?

Already tried :

1. **Makes view Non-Recyclable** -> that makes the scrolling very laggy
2. **Keep the timer for the adapter and not the view itself. Update the Entire ListView After the timer , instead of assigning timers for each OTP**  -> Works fine , but it makes the list blink after update , and again , makes scrolling a bit laggy after the update.

Comment: On second thought , could it be that 2 ( or more ) Timers are running at the same time holding the same view to update ? 

Hence , the data is being updated correctly first , but then also being updated with the wrong data !

Comment: I always a good thing to show some code. Show your diffUtil.